# Change google translate api html structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

When using the Google Translation API on a website, it delivers an HTML structure that include the translation options inside a selected tag.

I don't know if this even possible but I am wondering: is there any way to change this to a HMTL list or any other HTML structure??

Comment: There's a difference between the translation API and the translation bar that Chrome provides. I don't think you can modify that translation bar it's part of the browser.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to customize the translation API not the translation widget since it's part of the browser as you said.

Comment: The translation API just deals in raw data so you can display that however you want on your page, including in a select dropdown

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your specific request, but you can take a look at this example: https://codepen.io/allurewebsolutions/pen/BRdZdB if you want to customize the translation API.